# How to prevent a recursion error implementing factorial in Python

Tags: python, debugging, recursion, stack-trace, tail-recursion

I'm developing a math suite and am currently having issues implementing the recursive version of the factorial function. The issue is when I use it in my Bayesian combination function:

```
C(n,k) = n! / k! * (n-k)!
```

I've tested it independently and it works as it should, but as soon as I put it in my combination function, I get the error `Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`, even for very small values of n and k.

I've implemented an iterative solution which works perfectly, so why do I keep getting a recursion error?

Here's the recursive implementation:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

Here's the iterative implementation:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
```

And they are used in the combination function like so:

```
def combination(n, k):
    result = factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))
    return result
```

The recursive function seems to work only when k = 1.

Here are some sample outputs which produces the recursion error:

```
combination(2,1) = 2

combination(2,2) = 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "baysian.py", line 44, in <module>
    answer = combination(n, k)
  File "baysian.py", line 18, in combination
    result = factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k))
  File "baysian.py", line 9, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
  File "baysian.py", line 9, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
  File "baysian.py", line 9, in factorial
    return n * factorial(n - 1)
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "baysian.py", line 6, in factorial
    if n == 1:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: What is your question?  If you want to know which algorithm is faster, then time them.  Don't post speculative guessing here; you have the proper authority in front of you.  Look up how to use `timeit`, do the experiment, and post here with those results if there's a specific question you have.

Comment: Your recursive function does not guard against unexpected arguments, and will recurse infinitely (until it crashes) if the argument it receives is zero, negative, or a fraction.

Comment: I'm asking why my recursive factorial function  gives me the error 'maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' while my iterative one doesn't.

Comment: Of course the iterative one doesn't throw a recursion error. It isn't using recursion.

Comment: Can you provide an example where `combination` overflows, but the recursive `factorial` does not? As a side note, the factorial formula is not really suitable for computing binomial coefficients, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients for other options.

Comment: @georg I'm not sure what you mean by showing where `combination` overflows but I know that the recursive solution works only when `k = 1`

Comment: You said: `I get the error Recursion Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, even for very small values of n and k.` - post some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: consider editing your post with the actual question and the specific part of the code you have questions about.

Comment: What happens when you call the recursive version of `factorial(0)`?

Comment: @Woodford I got a recurssion error, but I've edited the code to handle that case.

Comment: @CobraPi Are you sure that 0! == 0?

Comment: @Woodford ugh I completely overlooked that. I think that was what was causing this error. Everything seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it) page:

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Then adjust with:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(<number>)
```

Will crash your machine if you enter a number too high

Comment: Yes, I've checked it out however increasing the limit causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my recursive factorial implementation was incorrect. It would return 0 for !0 instead of 1. I've added some changes and now it works. Here's my revised solution.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return n
    elif n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```